Can't get default fonts intermix with DejaVu font in text and math modes to work
I'm using TeXlive 2024 with XeLaTeX to compile.
In the code below, there is an issue.
Some of the symbols don't show up or not correct, such as \in, \geq,
\symbfit{x}, \symbf{\beta}, \triangleq.
If I comment out
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.8]{DejaVuSans}

Of course DejaVu font won't work, but all symbols are displayed correctly
in math and text modes.
Appreciate some help on this. Thank you - Tom.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{dsfont}

%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[scaled=0.8]{DejaVuSans}

\usepackage{unicode-math} % To support \symbf, \symbfit

\begin{document}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n} % Use different font type for \mathcal

Here's DejaVu intermixed with other font types in math mode:
\[
F(\text{\fontfamily{DejaVuSans-TLF}\selectfont dejavuvar}) \triangleq
  \frac{1}{\lvert \mathcal{D}_{\mathrm{data1}} \rvert}
  \sum_{\symbf{\theta} \in \mathds{R}, \symbf{\theta} \geq 10}
  f(\symbfit{x},\symbf{\beta})
  + \tfrac{1}{2} \mathcal{N}(x | y) \quad\text{bogus equation for testing}
\]

Here's DejaVu in text mode: \fontfamily{DejaVuSans-TLF}\selectfont dejavu,
followed by italic text \textit{italic text},
followed by bold text \textbf{bold text}
and regular text.

\end{document}


You should never use \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} with xetex, so incorrect characters and incorrect hyphenation are expected if you do that. What is the intention? It explicitly forces 8bit processing and breaks all unicode support, when you are using opentype unicode fonts

dejavu sans font is an opentype font so you can load it directly using fontspec \setmainfont or \newfontfamily you do not want to force loading an 8-bit subset of that designed for pdftex

David, thank you for enlightened me. The two comments helped me to get it to work.

You should never use \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} with xetex, so incorrect characters and incorrect hyphenation are expected if you do that. What is the intention? It explicitly forces 8bit processing and breaks all unicode support, when you are using opentype unicode fonts.
dejavu sans font is an opentype font so you can load it directly using fontspec \setmainfont or \newfontfamily. You do not want to force loading an 8-bit subset of that designed for pdftex.
